# Disable jenkins build slaves from a job

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I would like a periodic job that rebuilds jenkins build slaves, but I don't want it to fire if jobs are currently running.  My thoughts are either to

- consume all possible build slots on a slave, or
- disable the slave from the job and wait for it to go idle

I don't know how to do either from a job.  Is it possible?  Maybe another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way I'm going to solve this is to use the "launch slave via script" option.  The slave has options for periodically turning the slave off, and then I can just use the script to clean it up, rebuild it, and relaunch the slave.

The offline process has safeguards to make sure it won't happen when a build is executing.